# WSO2 APIM subscription work flow in distributed deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've tried working on the API Manager subscription workflow in a single instance and it's working fine. Now I want the same to be performed on a distributed deployment environment. Can I know on which node shall I update the SubscriptionCallbackService.epr path and on which node I should enable the " Engaging the WS Workflow Executor in the API Manager ".

Note:
We are using EI 6.5.0 and APIM 2.6.0 and 3.1.0 in two different environments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the `<API-M_HOME>/business-processes/epr` (any of the apim nodes) folder to `<EI_HOME>/wso2/business-process/repository/conf/epr`, **SubscriptionCallbackService** following value should be updated, Gateway port is 8243 if you have not done any offset.

```
 <wsa:Address>https://<APIM_GATEWAY_IP>:PORT/services/WorkflowCallbackService</wsa:Address>
```

"Engaging the WS Workflow Executor in the API Manager" should be done in the devportal node